# Mypy build task fails in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, mypy

I created a task in vscode however it errors when run.

Build Task task.json

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [{
        "label": "mypy",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "mypy",
        "args": [
            "($file)"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        }
    }]
}
```

The error I receive is

```
> Executing task: mypy ($file) <

/bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `$file'
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: `mypy ($file)'
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `${file}` to get currently opened file details.

Reference: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference